# Define remote Notary service

Tags: corda

I am playing around with the Yo!-example CorDapp, version `3.0.9`.

How can I deploy the contents of `yo-cordapp\build\nodes\Notary` to a remote server and use it as my notary instance?

I tried

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=RemoteNotary,C=GB"
        notary = [validating : true]
        p2pAddress("1.2.3.4")
        p2pPort 10002
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    }
```

but this does not work since the notary service is still looked up at "localhost:10002" as I can see in the logs.

However, although I just started services for PartyA and PartyB (and explicitly no notary service) I can send a Yo! from PartyA to PartyB although there is no notary service present?
Maybe I misunderstood the concept of a notary but I thought when `FINALIZING`a flow the `NotaryService` is invoked and required to sign the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

A notary is only required when either of the following are true:

- The transaction has 1+ input states
- The transaction has a timewindow

In the case of sending a Yo!, neither applies, so the notary does not see the transaction.

In terms of allowing the nodes to see the remote notary, take a look at the documentation here: https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html. You either need to:

- Create a network map server that tells each node where to find the other nodes
- Create a `node.conf` file for each node that already has the IP of the final machine where the notary will end up, then run the bootstrapper. See the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/setting-up-a-corda-network.html#bootstrapping-the-network